# MS Access sort columns of a table with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table where the order of the columns got messed up.

Is there a way to sort the columns by column name in vba?

In the data sheet view I can drag and drop them.
And in VBA there is a field property called ColumnOrder.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224067(v=office.11).aspx

But it looks like I have to call each field by name and set the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .. it looks like I have to call each field by name and set the
>   property.

That's exactly what to do.

You'll have to read the field names, order them as you want, then set the *ColumnOrder* property according to your chosen field sequence.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure if there is an easier way.